# I can't install ionic

Tags: installation, ionic-framework

I was trying to install ionic framework as explaned on their [site](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)
but i always get this error. I googled a lot to find a solution but every solution I tried failed, can someone help me?

(I use win8 and the 32bit version of nodejs)

[image: error message]

Comment: Like the error says: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Already answered please visit http://stackoverflow.com/a/31124491/1276616

Comment: did you install nodejs with npm package ..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

before installing ionic

Comment: i do this but when i try to create project in ionic ..cmd says "ionic is not used as internal or external command" can u plz help me out .